# Nginx rewrite: remove .html from URL with arguments

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How can i remove the .html from an url with argument?

eg:
http://www.domain.com/somepage.html?argument=whole&bunch=a-lot

to:

http://www.domain.com/somepage?argument=whole&bunch=a-lot

I have tried

```
    location / {
    index index.html index.php; 
            rewrite ^\.html(.*)$ $1 last;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; 
            expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
     }
```

and a bunch of other suggestions, but can't seem to make it work....

Tnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your configuration like this:

```
# rewrite html extensions
rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;

location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    # this way nginx first tries to serve the file as an .html although it doesn't have the extension
    try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ @handler;
}
```

Ofcourse you can add any cache settings etc. but this should be enough to remove the .html part.